# C++20-ranges: reuse of a filter view

Tags: c++, c++20

I do not understand the result of the following code (C++20 compiled with g++-10):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    
    auto v = vector<int>{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    auto r = v | views::filter([](int n) {return n % 3 == 0;});
    ranges::generate(r,[]() { return 2; });
    auto s = v | views::filter([](int n) {return n % 3 == 0;});
    
    cout << "v: ";
    for(auto x: v) cout << x << " ";
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "r: ";
    for (auto x: r) cout << x << " " ;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "s: ";
    for (auto x: s) cout << x << " " ;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

On my machine, the result is:

```
v: 2 1 2 2 4 5 2 7 
r: 2 
s:
```

I understand the first (`v`) and the third lines (`s`): in v, integers divisible by 3 are replaced by 2 (first line) and thus afterwards no integer is divisible by 3 anymore. Thus the third line is empty.

But why does the second line (`r`) display a unique value 2 and is different from the third line ???

If I replace the 2 by 3 in the ranges::generate then the result is normal:

```
v: 3 1 2 3 4 5 3 7 
r: 3 3 3 
s: 3 3 3
```

Maybe the reason is trivial but I did not find any reason in the documentation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are violating [[range.filter.iterator]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter#iterator-1):

> Modification of the element a `filter_­view​::​iterator` denotes is permitted, but results in undefined behavior if the resulting value does not satisfy the filter predicate.

Your predicate here is elements divisible by 3, and you're modifying all of those to be `2` - which does not satisfy the predicate. That's undefined behavior. Don't do that.

In your followup example, you're modifying elements, but they still satisfy the predicate - so this is fine.

---

The reason this is the case is that `filter` has to cache its `begin()` iterator to satisfy the amortized O(1) constant requirement. What ends up happening is that during the `generate`, the `filter` looks for the first element that satisfies the predicate (which in this case is the very first element, the `0`). That result is cached.

You then overwrite that value to `2`, which is no longer divisible by `3`, but the `filter`'s `begin()` still refers to it. Which is why it gets printed.

When you create a *new* `filter`, that one doesn't have its `begin()` cached yet so there's no such issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had not managed to find this documentation even with google requests... This is a sad answer because what I did was one of the first things I've thought about while discovering ranges: modifying entries of a container selected according to some condition. 

What would be the nice way ? Using `replace_if` in the context above ? More generally I was looking for a nice way of expressing some `generate_if`.

Comment: The [reference site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is not clear at all about which "constrained algorithms" can be used with the "various views". Incompatibility such as the one I rediscovered randomly should be presented in a clearer way. Are there such other well-known incompatibilities ? A good reference for a half-beginner would be interesting: the c++draft is a bit tough to begin with ranges for me.

Comment: @DamienSimon Yeah the draft is not intended to be reference for the user, it's intended as a reference for the implementation. I agree it would be nice to have a good way of presenting this sort of information, since it's quite subtle.